# Can not read property 'position' undefined, get Coordinates - CustomTile - Openseadragon

Tags: coordinates, deepzoom, seadragon, openseadragon

I am trying to get the coordinates with below code : If i am clicking on the canvas to grab the X and Y position : showing me console error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

screenshot : http://screencast.com/t/0LHAae5AicRz

```
viewer.addHandler('canvas-click', function (target, info) {
            var viewportPoint = viewer.viewport.pointFromPixel(info.position);
            var imagePoint = viewer.viewport.viewportToImageCoordinates(viewportPoint.x, viewportPoint.y);
            console.log(imagePoint.x, imagePoint.y);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The info parameter is probably not what you think it is.

Do `console.log(info)` to see what the variable is in the console.

Perhaps the variable you are looking for is another parameter.

Also log all the arguments that get passed to the function. Write this *inside* the function:

`console.log(arguments)`

This way you will be able to inspect the variables and find the data you need.

Comment: console.log(info); ::--> "undefined"

Comment: Ok, what about arguments?

Answer (score 0):

This way, I can remove the canvas-click related - position of undefined error : Take a look at here for the answer : https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/318

For the //! OpenSeadragon 1.1.1, please updated the code as per below.

```
viewer.addHandler('canvas-click', function (event)
        {
            console.log(event);
            var viewportPoint = viewer.viewport.pointFromPixel(event.position);
            var imagePoint = viewer.viewport.viewportToImageCoordinates(viewportPoint.x, viewportPoint.y);
            console.log(imagePoint.x, imagePoint.y);
        });
```